# Are recording recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I see that requests for recommendations for listening are discouraged but it is less obvious whether requests for recommendations for a recording of a specific piece are accepted.  For example: what are particularly good recordings of Bach's Toccata and Fugue in D mino?

Comment: I'd be against it, because by nature it's so subjective. However, it would be a cool resource to have. Maybe a community wiki here on meta or a dedicated chat room.

Comment: It could be on-topic if the recommendation is based on objective criteria, and concrete facts. *Particularly good* is subjective, "the earliest", "the slowest", "conducted by this person", "recording during this decade" etc are objective.